Undesired blank space
Im working on a poster for a presentation im going to give, but the formatting is all wrong. I was using a poster template that devides the page into 3 colums, but i decided to change it so that the abstract is at the top and in one colum to itself, but now i have a gigant blank space that just wont go away. Im genuently desperate. 
The code:
\begin{document}
\conference{{\bf Expo Ingeniería 2024}, Tecnológico de Monterrey, Campus Ciudad de México}

\maketitle
\hrule\vspace{0.2cm} 
\vspace{1cm} 

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.79\textwidth}  
    \textbf{The project involves} the development of a six-degree-of-freedom robotic arm designed for cinema and video applications, featuring a horizontal reach of one meter and a payload capacity of up to 2.5 kilograms. The use of an amateur or semi-professional camera and its lens is permitted. \textbf{The project was divided into two phases: the first phase focuses on state-of-the-art research, selection of key components, actuator design, and mechanical design. The second phase encompasses the implementation of kinematics, communication, and assembly.} \\
    During the current semester, the first phase was completed. Initially, a feasibility analysis was conducted based on the state-of-the-art in robotic arms, the film industry, and the application of robotics within it. This analysis defined key parameters for the robot, such as reach, speed, payload capacity, weight, and cost. Based on these parameters, \textbf{BLDC motors, Moteurs R4.1 controllers, and a cycloidal gear reduction system were selected, and the CAD design of the robotic arm was initiated.}
    
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.02\textwidth} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{arm bot.png} 
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm} 
\hrule\vspace{0.5cm} 

%%%rest of the poster


Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I suggest you issue the instruction
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

in the preamble and change the code chunk
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.79\textwidth}  
    \textbf{The project involves} the development of a six-degree-of-freedom robotic arm designed for cinema and video applications, featuring a horizontal reach of one meter and a payload capacity of up to 2.5 kilograms. The use of an amateur or semi-professional camera and its lens is permitted. \textbf{The project was divided into two phases: the first phase focuses on state-of-the-art research, selection of key components, actuator design, and mechanical design. The second phase encompasses the implementation of kinematics, communication, and assembly.} \\
    During the current semester, the first phase was completed. Initially, a feasibility analysis was conducted based on the state-of-the-art in robotic arms, the film industry, and the application of robotics within it. This analysis defined key parameters for the robot, such as reach, speed, payload capacity, weight, and cost. Based on these parameters, \textbf{BLDC motors, Moteurs R4.1 controllers, and a cycloidal gear reduction system were selected, and the CAD design of the robotic arm was initiated.}
    
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.02\textwidth} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, 
                     keepaspectratio]{test.png} 
\end{minipage}

to
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.79\textwidth}  % don't use '[t]' option
\textbf{The project involves} the development of a six-degree-of-freedom robotic arm designed for cinema and video applications, featuring a horizontal reach of one meter and a payload capacity of up to 2.5 kilograms. The use of an amateur or semi-professional camera and its lens is permitted. \textbf{The project was divided into two phases: the first phase focuses on state-of-the-art research, selection of key components, actuator design, and mechanical design. The second phase encompasses the implementation of kinematics, communication, and assembly.} 
    
During the current semester, the first phase was completed. Initially, a feasibility analysis was conducted based on the state-of-the-art in robotic arms, the film industry, and the application of robotics within it. This analysis defined key parameters for the robot, such as reach, speed, payload capacity, weight, and cost. Based on these parameters, \textbf{BLDC motors, Moteurs R4.1 controllers, and a cycloidal gear reduction system were selected, and the CAD design of the robotic arm was initiated.}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.02\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[valign=c,
                 width=0.19\textwidth, % 0.19 = 1.00 - 0.79 - 0.02
                 keepaspectratio]{test.png}

I.e., do not use the t placement option on the first minipage and don't wrap the \includegraphics statement in a minipage. Instead, add the option valign=c to the list of optional arguments of \includegraphics.

A compilable example and its output:

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry} % just for this example
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.79\textwidth} % do _not_ use '[t]' option
\textbf{The project involves} the development of a six-degree-of-freedom robotic arm designed for cinema and video applications, featuring a horizontal reach of one meter and a payload capacity of up to 2.5 kilograms. The use of an amateur or semi-professional camera and its lens is permitted. \textbf{The project was divided into two phases: the first phase focuses on state-of-the-art research, selection of key components, actuator design, and mechanical design. The second phase encompasses the implementation of kinematics, communication, and assembly.} 
    
During the current semester, the first phase was completed. Initially, a feasibility analysis was conducted based on the state-of-the-art in robotic arms, the film industry, and the application of robotics within it. This analysis defined key parameters for the robot, such as reach, speed, payload capacity, weight, and cost. Based on these parameters, \textbf{BLDC motors, Moteurs R4.1 controllers, and a cycloidal gear reduction system were selected, and the CAD design of the robotic arm was initiated.}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.02\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[valign=c,
                 width=0.19\textwidth, 
                 keepaspectratio]{test.png} 

\end{document}


You don't show important parts, such as the document class.
However, the following code should work in your setup. First, a couple of things to note:

never use \\ to end paragraphs;
there should be a tie ~ between 2.5 and kilograms;
pay attention to endlines that produce spaces (see \end{minipage}\hfill).

The key for the alignment is valign=t, provided by adjustbox.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}  
  \textbf{The project involves} the development of 
  a six-degree-of-freedom robotic arm designed for
  cinema and video applications, featuring a horizontal
  reach of one meter and a payload capacity of up to
  2.5~kilograms. The use of an amateur or semi-professional
  camera and its lens is permitted. \textbf{The project was
  divided into two phases: the first phase focuses on
  state-of-the-art research, selection of key components,
  actuator design, and mechanical design. The second phase
  encompasses the implementation of kinematics, communication,
  and assembly.}
 
  During the current semester, the first phase was completed.
  Initially, a feasibility analysis was conducted based on the
  state-of-the-art in robotic arms, the film industry, and the
  application of robotics within it. This analysis defined key
  parameters for the robot, such as reach, speed, payload capacity,
  weight, and cost. Based on these parameters, \textbf{BLDC motors,
  Moteurs R4.1 controllers, and a cycloidal gear reduction system
  were selected, and the CAD design of the robotic arm was initiated.}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image} 

\end{document}



thank you verry much for all the answers. at the end I went without the image in the abstract, but i will try all this methods for future reference

Instead of [t], try with the [b] or no option after \begin{minipage}.
The code you have supplied aligns the baseline of the [t]op line of the minipage with the surrounding text---hence the blank space. You probably want to align the [b]ottom or [c]enter (the default).
